# Azure Copy Files from Source Folder to Target Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions

For example we have a project folder say `"Sample Project"` and a blank folder `"TargetSampleProject"`.

What I need to do is to copy all the files from `"Sample Project"` into `"TargetSampleProject"`

Comment: This question is a little light on detail. Are you doing this in a build pipeline? Release pipeline? Are you using yaml or classic interface? Are you using the Copy Files Task, and if so how have you configured it?

Comment: I am new to this, so, No, I just need a simple c# code to make it work through a program.

Comment: Your question title and tags are very misleading if you just want to know how to copy files with C#. Look at `System.IO.File`. I'm sure you will find many resources online for how to copy files.

Comment: Well, from a c# code I want to access all files from a project folder which is on Azure and then I need to copy those files into the another project folder which is also on Azure. I hope it's clear now?

Comment: I don't know what a "project folder on Azure" is. Do you mean Azure Repos source control?

Comment: Yes @Crowcoder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214346/discussion-between-nrsharma-and-crowcoder).

Answer (score 0):

To copy all the files in one directory to another directory, get the files in the source folder. You could refer to the code as below and the official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders#example).

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
{
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

    // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
        destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
    }
}
```